# is my google app engine deployed source code secure?

Tags: python, security, google-app-engine, passwords, credentials

I'm thinking about [good ways to store third party credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994112/i-must-store-third-party-credentials-in-my-database-best-way), which basically means there needs to be a secret somewhere, either in code or data. I'm deploying on google app engine.

If the 'secret' was something like

```
pw_passphrase = sha2(username + 'global-password')
pw_plaintext = aes_decrypt(pw_passphrase, pw_ciphertext)
```

can I depend on this code never being seen by a non appengine administrator?

...what if the credentials protect something supersensitive like personal financial data, do we still trust it?

(The sha2 bit is exchangable with any other secret [pseudo-random function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-random_function).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes: your source code **is** secure (as secure as Google can make it), and there's no way for unauthorized third parties to peek.

Comment: there's no **known** way for unauthorized third parties to peek.

Comment: @Teddy, sure, anybody interested can check my Google profile, wikipedia entry, interviews, etc -- it's hardly secret;-). However, I always speak for myself, and myself only (I'm not authorized to speak for Google nor for other firms).

@Vinko, sure, one can't "prove a negative" (e.g., I can't _prove_ the NSA hasn't already cracked every code in existence or yet to be invented, and is routinely monitoring every bit every second;-).

Answer (score 2):

Also remember to handle exceptions in your code with an error page, or else an exception thrown might uncover your source code to an unsigned user.

Comment: wow thank you for this. definitely another reason to sandbox the sensitive stuff to its own dedicated, simple app.

Comment: @GAE supports custom error page too isn't is ? Anyway I think some standard audits such FISMA compliance would bring a lot more trust to the GAE platform.